# Swagger query parameter template

Tags: swagger, swagger-ui

I have on query parameter which is little bit complex and i have my own syntax to make that value. Its has more then one variable to make one complete string value.
Let suppose name of parameter is index which has row and column like to make this value `20:30`

```
index =  { row: 20, col:30 }
index2 = { row: 20, col:30, chr: 15 }
```

Now i wanted to make it as

```
example.com?index=20:30
example.com?index2=20:30:15
```

Can someone tell me how can i define this in swagger ?
Thank you.

Comment: Swagger is 'just' a representational layer on top of your API. It shouldn't be abused to transform a template in the URI.

Comment: I can understand that its a "representational layer" on my api. My point was is it possible in swagger to construct any field from object. SO according to your comment swagger does not support it. Thank you

Comment: `:` is not a commonly used separator. Can you use `,` `|` or `%20`instead? The latter are standard array separators in OpenAPI/Swagger.

Comment: @Helen `:` is just an example to explain my use-case. I am using all of them in my case. `,`, `|` and `:` because i have little bit complex format of my parameter 's value.

Answer (score 1):

Make your swagger parameter a string and in your code behind handle the splitting into multiple variables...

I do exactly that here:
http://turoapi.azurewebsites.net/swagger/ui/index#/Echo/Echo_Get

```
"parameters": [
{
    "name": "location",
    "in": "query",
    "description": "SoFL= 26.16,-80.20",
    "required": true,
    "type": "string"
},
```

That location is (Latitude,Longitude) and I split it with a C# TypeConverter
...and the request looks like:
http://turoapi.azurewebsites.net/api/Echo?location=26.16,-80.20

The code for that WebApi is here:
https://github.com/heldersepu/TuroApi

Comment: I saw your example. it is sending three parameters and i want only one parameter. that is y i asked for custom template that I will give object and it will parse it in one field according to my defined template.

Comment: Yes my example it is sending three parameters, but Focus on the ***location*** parameter that does exactly what you need

Comment: I changed the example to a simpler controller that has only the ***location***  parameter

Comment: As I understand location is normal string parameter. and you have to provide two comma separated values `26.16,-80.20` as a string. Am I right ? and user can send anything he want like in your example user can send `/Echo?location=testing"`
And i want to provide for location two input text fields and then swagger will join them according to my template.

Comment: I think you are missing the point of swagger... Swagger won't join anything for you. _ _ _  And in my WebAPI location is not a normal string parameter, if you look at the code it is a GeoPoint, but the only way that swagger can represent this type is with a string, but if you don't pass the correct format (like ```/Echo?location=testing```)  it will error out.

Comment: But that error is coming from server side. it has nothing to do with swagger. My server will also throw an error but i also wanted to handle it on swagger side too. Thank you for your time.

Comment: Yes exactly my point! the solution to your problem has nothing to do with swagger. There is nothing swagger can do to join or split a query string parameter.