# How to define a query parameter with multiple values separated by equals signs (=)?

Tags: swagger, openapi

I have an API with this URL:

```
/api/doSomething?key=value1=value2
```

Can this be represented in Swagger/OpenAPI 3.0? And if so, how would that look like? Without the second `value2` I would specify it like this:

```
  /api/doSomething:
    get:
      summary: ''
      parameters:
      - in: path
        name: key
        description: ''
        required: true
        schema:
          type: string
```

Comment: Is `?key=value1=value2` the correct format? The commonly used formats are `?key1=value1&key2=value2` and `key=value1,value2`.

Comment: It is the format which is used by the API I'm trying to describe. It looks strange for me too. So I guess there is no way to reflect this with Swagger?

Comment: `=` as a value delimiter is not supported. You'll need to define the parameter as `type: string` and split the value on the server side. As explained here - [Swagger query parameter template](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45485397/113116).

Comment: @Helen If you want you can post your comment as answer as this works for me and I don't think that there is a better solution for this strange API design.

Answer (score 1):

OpenAPI supports the following array value separators in the query string: `, | %20`. OpenAPI 2.0 also supports `\t`.

`=` is NOT supported as a separator for array values.

The most you can do is document your `key` parameter as `type: string` and explain the format in the `description`. Assuming you use `openapi: 3.0.0`:

```yaml
parameters:
  - in: query
    name: filter
    required: true
    schema:
      type: string
    description: A list of values separated by `=`.
    example: value1=value2
```

Also note that `=` is a [reserved character](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13500078/113116). In OpenAPI 3.0, query parameters have the additional [`allowReserved`](https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/blob/master/versions/3.0.1.md#user-content-parameterAllowReserved) attribute that controls whether reserved characters should be sent as-is or percent-encoded.

```
allowReserved: true
/api/doSomething?key=value1=value2
                           ^ 
allowReserved: false
/api/doSomething?key=value1%3Dvalue2
                            ^
```

Answer (score 0):

The [Parameter Object](https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/blob/master/versions/3.0.0.md#parameter-object) may contain a `allowReserved` option that allows the use of reserved characters like `=` in the parameter value. Does the following work for you?

```
/api/doSomething:
   get:
     summary: ''
     parameters:
     - in: path
       name: key
       description: ''
       required: true
       allowReserved: true
       schema:
         type: string
```